# Does C preprocessor directives recompute each time?

Tags: c, preprocessor, compiler-directives

I have this line of code:

```
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 'z' - 'a' + 1
```

When I hover over ALPHABET_SIZE anywhere in my code it tells me that it expands to `'z' - 'a' + 1`.
So I wondered if this expression has to be recomputed each time I use ALPHABET_SIZE in my code? If so, how can I prevent the recomputation?

Comment: Feasible, just curious.

Comment: I'd expect that would be computed by the compiler at compile time and your code would just have 26s in it, unless you're deliberately compiling with optimization off.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that optimization takes care of it automatically?

Comment: But beware of `'z'-'a' +1`. Use `('z'-'a'+1)`, otherwise, something like `4*ALPHABET_SIZE` will give you surprising results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 'z' - 'a' + 1
```

The pre-processor replaces each `ALPHABET_SIZE`

With

```
'z' - 'a' + 1
```

The compiler then will most probably perform [Constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) optimization replacing the computation with 26.

---

Demo https://godbolt.org/z/Mo46db, the expression is replaced by `26` with gcc 10.2

Answer (score 4):

The C standard only specifies the observable behavior of the programs, not how they work under the hood.

Whether or not `'z' - 'a' + 1` is recomputed every time doesn't affect the observable behavior, so it's up to the implementation to decide.

In general, you can expect sensible compilers to compute the result at compile-time, especially when optimizations are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following program:

```
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 'z' - 'a' + 1

#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", 2*ALPHABET_SIZE);
    printf("%d\n", ALPHABET_SIZE*2);
}
```

In my C implementation, this prints “148” and “27”. This occurs because, in the first `printf`, `2*ALPHABET_SIZE` is replaced with `2*'z' - 'a' + 1`, which is evaluated as `(2*'z') - 'a' + 1`, and, in the second `printf`, `ALPHABET_SIZE*2` is replaced with `'z' - 'a' + 1*2`, which is evaluated as `'z' - 'a' + (1*2)`. Since those produce two different results, it proves that preprocessing with C semantics does not replace a macro with a single expression result computed once; it must produce something else (actually a sequence of *preprocessor tokens*) that is subsequently reinterpreted in context.